# chrome - input["file"] click() does not work when select element 'onchange' triggers it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, yui

JsBin - http://jsbin.com/puri/7/edit

What is happening is I am trying to simulate .click() on file["input"] on two scenarios.

1. Trigger file["input"].click() when 'click' triggered on a button
2. Trigger file["input"].click() when 'change' triggered on a select

Scenarios 1 & 2 works on Firefox latest. But only 1 works on Chrome latest. What could be causing this problem? Is this how this is supposed to work?

I am on Mac osx 10.9.1

Comment: What happens if you `file["input"].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));`?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) method does not always trigger handlers as expected, depending on it's origin, target and the browser used. For a more consistent outcome, use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) with a custom *click Event*.

```
someNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: It didn't work on Firefox/Chrome. Updated jsbin using this http://jsbin.com/puri/12/edit

Comment: that's weird. The jsbin does not work for me on Chrome v32 on mac

Comment: I managed to make it work in chrome using this trick, but at first I thought it doesn't work, because I tried to use it from the console. I guess chrome will let it pass as long as it was initiated by the person browsing the site (apparently console doesn't count).

Comment: they dont' work anymore, why??